# How to make scroll to top button appear after scrolling in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, scroll

I have created a scroll to the top component form my angular project and I trying to make my scroll image appear only after a user scroll down but my button is still appearing on the initial load so any idea or suggestion on how can I achieve that

so what I'm trying to do is,

1. when the page is load, don't show the scroll icon
2. when user scroll down the page, show the the scroll icon

HTML

```
<div class="to-top" (click)="scrollToTop()" [ngClass]="{ 'show-scrollTop': windowScrolled }">
  <img src="../../../../assets/marketing-site/ecosystem/Scroll-to-Top.svg" alt="to-top-icon" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.to-top {
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 8px 12px 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

.show-scrollTop {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

TS

```
  scrollToTop(): void {
    // scroll to the top of the body
    return this.document.body.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start',
      inline: 'start',
    });
  }
```

Here is the example I created pls check it out

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2d5jrt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I think you're missing `opacity: 0` in your `.to-top` class.

Comment: @TotallyNewb I just added but still appearing on the initial load. I just want the button to appear immediately if user scroll down only. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS

```
.to-top {
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 8px 12px 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show-scrollTop {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

TS

```
  windowScrolled = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      this.windowScrolled = window.pageYOffset !== 0;
    });
  }
```

This should do the job.

Also, for scrolling I'll prefer:

```
  scrollToTop(): void {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this but some reason my scroll icon is not even showing up anymore, any idea?.. :(. here is stackblitz example I created https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2d5jrt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: ah ok.. It work. my css class was wrong. that's why. THANK YOU for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression

```js
if (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTo || document.body.scrollTop > 20) {
      this.windowScrolled = true;
}
```

is always true. You probably meant something like this

```js
if( window.pageXOffset > 20 || document.body.scrollTop > 20) {}
```

`document.documentElement.scrollTo` is a function so it doesn't make sense to check if it exists in the condition I think.

Comment: Hi..just added but still appearing on the initial load. I just want the button to appear immediately if user scroll down only. :(

Comment: I think you would have to provide stackblitz or something because there is nothing more we can advise based on the code.

Comment: Hi I just create the stackblitz so can you pls check it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2d5jrt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: ```opacity: 0; ``` for the class ```.to-top``` is missing there.